# Android Wear Using Matrix to rotate hand on specific pivot point

Tags: matrix, time, rotation, wear-os

I'm trying to rotate a clock hand for an Android Wear watch face (a bitmap), but I can't seem to figure out how to set a specific point in the hand to rotate on using a Matrix.rotate. (The rotation point in the hand is about 20 pixels in from the bottom).

My understanding would be I would need to set the pivot point... as well as the rotation point (centerX, centerY). then rotate a specific degree.

Here's what I've got but the pivot point doesn't work.

```
// set pivot point
    handSecondMatrix.setTranslate(mCenterX - (mHandSecondBitmap.getWidth() * 0.375f), (mCenterY - (mHandSecondBitmap.getHeight() * 0.8744f)));

// set rotation    
    handSecondMatrix.setRotate(rotation);

// set center point to rotate on
    handSecondMatrix.postTranslate(mCenterX, mCenterY);

// draw hand
    canvas.drawBitmap(mHandSecondBitmap, handSecondMatrix, mHandSecondPaintBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
// Draw Hour Hand
handHourMatrix.reset();
handHourMatrix.setRotate(rotHr, mHandHourBitmapAmbient.getWidth() / 2, mHandHourBitmapAmbient.getHeight() * 0.958f);
handHourMatrix.postTranslate(mCenterX - (mHandHourBitmapAmbient.getWidth() / 2), mCenterY - (mHandHourBitmapAmbient.getHeight() * 0.958f));
canvas.drawBitmap(mHandHourBitmapAmbient, handHourMatrix, mHandHourPaintBitmap);
```